# ArcGIS polyline dangling endpoints count

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, complexity

Is there a way for count the number of dangling endpoints of a polyline? I need that because I would like to define a feature complexity parameter. For example, on the image below, the number of dangling endpoints of the selected feature is 6

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  I'm thinking you could 1) convert to single part, 2) intersect the feature class with itself to create points, 3) remove any points that overlap with each other, 4) join those points back onto the original features to get a count

Comment: There are ***always*** two endpoints per linear part.  You appear to want a count of **dangling** endpoints, which is different.

Comment: Feature to vertices, dangles ?

Comment: As @FelixIP said, Feature Vertices to Points with the dangle option will create points *only* on the dangling ends and a quick spatial join will yield a count of dangling ends... however Feature Vertices to Points https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000 is an advanced license tool, if you don't have an advanced license you'll have to be a bit more creative.

Comment: No need in spatial join, points will have line attributes.

Comment: As @FelixIP said, Feature Vertices to Point with dangle option. After i did a spatial join that counted, for each polyline feature, the dangle endpoints number. The goal is reached